# need to sync Mercurial and Team Foundation Server(TFS)

Tags: mercurial, tfs, synchronization

my company is using mercurial and the client is using TFS. we need a 2 way sync process??
if there are some changes in TFS these should be reflected in mercurial and vice versa
need some solution
like if v made some batch process etc
thnx in advance

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen anything about an hg-tfs process, but there is one for [git (git-tfs)](https://github.com/spraints/git-tfs)... Kinda hokey, but may provide an option in conjunction with [hg-git](http://hg-git.github.com/).

You'd still have to write up some scripts and such to automate the communication between the servers.

Alternatively, maybe the git-tfs project could be a good starting place for a new hg-tfs project :)

Answer (score 1):

We had to do a one-time conversion of a TFS repo into Mercurial, and didn't find any good way to do it. Initially we wanted to use `[tfs2svn]`, and then `hg convert` the SVN repo.

Alas, `tfs2svn` isn't stable when it comes to complex renames and branching. I managed to convert a small repo that way, but had to write a custom `tfs2hg` utility to convert another repo, with 2 years worth of history.

If you find a solution, please post an answer.